# Is this partition table OK?

Tags: partitioning

I made my own partition table. The system is running fine but I doubt that I made it correctly.
Some people say that the swap must go at the end, so I don't know if this partition is correct:

```
/dev/sda1 = linux-swap
/dev/sda2: (extended)
    /dev/sda5 ext2=boot
    /dev/sda6 ext4= /
    /dev/sda3 ext4=Home
```

Answer (score 0):

The swap partition doesn't need to be at the end. I think that primarily happens because it's usually the last partition added to a table when it's being created.

[More info from The Linux Documentation Project](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Partition/#SwapSize)

Comment: So I suppose my partition table is Ok then!